# Using left join with query builder doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Having some problems retrieving ManytoOne relationships when using left join.

Before was using this query to query for conferences

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
->select('u.id,u.comment,
IDENTITY(u.place) AS place_id,
IDENTITY(u.sponsor) AS sponsor_id,
IDENTITY(u.tour) AS tour_id,
u.startat
');
```

Now I'm trying to left join with diffusion which is tied to the diffusion in a many to many relationship.

```
  $qbt = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u','c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Conference', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('p.diffusion', 'c');
```

However this query doesn't return the u.place, u.sponsor and u.tour which are ManyToOne relationships.

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: Assuming you have all your relations setup then the entities you mentioned will be lazy loaded.  Of course you are never actually selecting u so you query is not going to work regardless.

Comment: Personnaly, I "hate" QueryBuilder (or even DQL) when having to deal with joins. I go with NativeQuery class. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html I hope @Cerad intervene here and share with us his thought regarding this.

Comment: Couple of years ago I decided that Doctrine's ORM caused more problems than it was worth.  I reverted back to sql and so far it has worked well.

Comment: @Cerad, You are completely right. raw SQL is far better. The problem (for me at least) is not having enough knowledge and then not able to implement all the features of Doctrine, especially regarding security. Thank you for your insight

Comment: Don't read too much into my comment.  I have used Doctrine 2 since it's initial release.  For many use cases it is ideal.  DQL works great.  The nature of the projects I am currently working on has shifted and I started to hit some of D2's weaker spots.

Answer (score 1):

leftJoin must be followed by 'WITH'. So for example:

```
->leftJoin('p.diffusion', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.user=u.id', 'u.id');
```

But i think it's better to post both your entities so i can give you the exact answer.

Comment: Well no.  DQL is a bit smarter than SQL and infers the WITH clause from the mapping data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue , I had to add 
->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
to the getQuery , because getArrayResults by default doesn't return foreign keys( the place, sponsor and tour respectivly).

Here is my final query in the conference repository

```
        $qbt = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qbt->select('conference','diffusion')
        ->from('AppBundle:Conference', 'conference')
        ->leftJoin('conference.diffusion', 'diffusion');

    return $qbt
        ->getQuery()
        ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
        ->useQueryCache(true)
        ->useResultCache(true,3600)
        ->getArrayResult();
```